# Table View Group Header View

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to create an effect similar to the Open Table application.  I want the section header to stick to the top as I scroll the table.  This is of course the default behavior with a plain table view, but because of style, I want a group table view.

Any ideas or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the "Info" label or the "Details" label?

Comment: Yes the info label's view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it (I'd wager OpenTable does it this way) is to use a plain table style but dress the cells yourself as grouped.  You'd need 3 background images for the cells, one for the first cell in a section (with rounded upper corners), one for the last row in a section (with rounded lower corners), and one for the others that looks like grouped cells (with left and right insets).

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping of an easy way.  This would make sense considering there group table view cell lines are 2 pixels instead of 1 pixel

Comment: It shouldn't be too tough.  Just set up 3 background images.  A quick cheat is to first render your table in grouped style, then do a screen capture of a complete section, slice that image up into the top, middle and bottom sections, and viola.